# assign command output to variable in bash

Tags: linux, bash, variables

I am having problems trying to make a bash script.

this is the command:

```
ps -ef | grep "python ./" |awk '{print $2 }' | head -n 1
```

and here is how I save the variable

```
first =$(ps -ef | grep "python ./" |awk '{print $2 }' | head -n 1)
```

When I execute this script, the console says:

> ./test.sh: line3: 2748: order not found

What am I doing wrong? thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Variable assignment is like this: `var=$(command)`.

So in your case, you wrote one space too many. Instead of:

```
first =$(ps -ef | grep "python ./" |awk '{print $2 }' | head -n 1)
     ^
```

You need to write:

```
first=$(ps -ef | grep "python ./" |awk '{print $2 }' | head -n 1)
     ^
     no spaces around = !!
```

#### Why were you getting this error message?

> ./test.sh: line3: 2748: order not found

Because with `first XX`, Bash understands you are trying to run the command `first` with the parameters `XX`.

---

Addendum: to make the command more straightforward, without as many pipes, use a single `awk` as [suggested by Tom Fenech](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28034760/assign-command-output-to-variable-in-bash#comment44454473_28034770) (thanks!):

```
ps -ef | awk '/python \.\//{print $2; exit}'
               ^^^^^^^^^^   ^^^^^^^^  ^^^^
                    |          |      stop processing, to get 1 value
                    |       print the 2nd block
               match lines with python ./
```

Comment: Instead, write `awk '/python \.\//{print $2;exit}'`

Comment: @TomFenech this looks way better! Thanks, I included it into my answer.